# The kernel of the isogeny $[n]$ of an abelian variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be an abelian variety of dimension $g$ over a field $k$, and let $n$ be a positive integer such that $\mathop{\mathrm{char}}(k) \nmid n$. Is it true that the kernel of $[n]: A \to A$, considered as a finite flat group scheme over $k$ (i.e., the fiber product of the following diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
    \mathop{\mathrm{ker}}[n] @>{}>> A \\
    @V{}VV @V{[n]}VV \\
    k @>>{\varepsilon}> A
\end{CD}
$$
), is isomorphic to the constant sheaf defined by $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^{2g}$?

Comment: No! Look up Tate modules.

Comment: If $k$ is a finite field or more generally finitely generated over its prime field, this cannot possibly be true for all $n$, because $A(k)$ is finite (resp. finitely generated), hence only has finitely many torsion elements. (The statement $\ker[n] \cong (\mathbf Z/n)^{2g}$ is equivalent to $A[n](k) = A[n]$.)

Comment: It is however true if $k$ is algebraically closed — maybe this is what the OP had in mind?